# wired connection doesn't work

Tags: internet, connection, wired

I just installed ubuntu but I can't connect to internet. 
I tried the automatic dhcp (which it has always worked to me), I tried the manual and the wireless but nothing is working.

I have dual bot with windows that has no problem to connect.
also I installed ubuntu few months ago and it was working with no problem so I'm not sure what has changed.
I also tried the debian and linux mint live just to check but i have the same problem.

I tried to ask help in irc but not sure what else to do

when I used the manual setup I get the ip and eth0 seams to work but I can't receive any data, if i try to ping 192.168.x.x it says that it is unreacheable

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think sometime you need to update Ubuntu with Software updater and then only you can further proceed. To do this first you need to connect with wired network and update software updater and then i think you will be able to connect to WiFi.

I am giving this answer based on my experience because few months back i too have installed Ubuntu and i got same problem and i tried this way and then it worked. So try using this way.

Comment: yeah the problem is that the wired connection also doesn't work

Comment: Well in this case i don't have further idea how to solve this.

Comment: without the basic connection, I'm to able to update or download or fix anything... really don't know what to do.